# Updating SQL Server table with more information from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have imported data to an sql table from an Excel document which worked perfectly. Every excel row has like ten columns and I only imported five of them and apparently I need all of the ten columns now. And yes, I already have the columns in the database so I just need to fill in the missing information.

Is there a smooth way to import the rest of the data from the excel I didn't import earlier?

I probably can't remove all data and just import again with all of the data because this table is used as a FK in a bunch of other tables.

If you have questions because I wasn't clear enough, ask away!

Comment: Perform an `UPDATE` on the table with it in the `FROM` and perform a `JOIN` on a `OPENROWSET` query to the Excel File?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I attempted this but had issues with `OPENROWSET`. I couldn't read from Excel files with it (had some error message I tried to fix).

I ended up putting all the data from the excel in a new table (with same IDs) and used that new table instead to join in with the other tables. Atleast I got it to work.